# Spring Integration Mail IMAP - multiple receiver

Tags: spring, email, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using spring boot 2.2.4.RELEASE

I need to build a dynamic mail receiver because I can have several mail server where to fetch mails. The mail server must be configurable by other systems so my requirement is to be dynamically able in fetching messages.

I investigated and I liked the Spring Integration solution and its DSL (note: it's enough to me to simply download messages and their attachments, if any).

So I built this code:

```
String flowId = MAIL_IN_FLOW_ID_PREFIX+cpd.getIndirizzoMail();
if( flowContext.getRegistrationById(flowId) != null ) {
    flowContext.remove(flowId);
}
ImapMailInboundChannelAdapterSpec adapterSpec = Mail.imapInboundAdapter(connectionUrl.toString())
    .javaMailProperties(javaMailProperties)
    .shouldDeleteMessages(false)
    .shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(false)
    .selector(selectFunction);
if( confMailIn.isRichiedeAutenticazione() ) {
     adapterSpec = adapterSpec.javaMailAuthenticator(new CasellaPostaleAuthenticator(cpd.getUsername(), cpd.getPassword()));
}

IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
.from(adapterSpec.get(), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(pollingSeconds)).maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMailMessagePerPoll)))
.handle(message -> {

    logger.info("Message headers "+message.getHeaders());
    logger.info("Message payload "+message.getPayload());
})

.get();

flowContext.registration(flow).id(flowId).register();
```

I tried by using my gmail account. The code is able in connecting to GMAIL by imap but, when I try to simply log messages, I get this error:

> A6 OK Success
>
> 2020-02-05 12:48:41,835 23412 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG
>   o.s.i.mail.ImapMailReceiver - Received 10 messages
>
> 2020-02-05 12:48:41,836 23413 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG oA7 STORE 1
>   +FLAGS (\Flagged) .s.i.mail.ImapMailReceiver - USER flags are not supported by this mail server. Flagging message with system flag
>
> A7 NO STORE attempt on READ-ONLY folder (Failure)
>
> A8 CLOSE
>
> A8 OK Returned to authenticated state. (Success)
>
> DEBUG IMAP: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
>
> 2020-02-05 12:48:42,198 23775 [task-scheduler-1] ERROR
>   o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler -
>   org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred
>   while polling for mail; nested exception is
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: A7 NO STORE attempt on READ-ONLY folder
>   (Failure);   nested exception is:
>     com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A7 NO STORE attempt on
>   READ-ONLY folder (Failure)    at
>   org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.doReceive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:250)

Now it seems that by default the FOLDER is opened in READ_ONLY way and this seems to cause an error.

I'm stucked here and I can't figure out how to solve the issue.

May anybody give me a tip?

Thank you

Angelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> adapterSpec.get()

Issuing a `get()` on the spec circumvents Spring's bean initialization logic which switches the folder to read/write.

Either make the adapter a `@Bean` or simply remove the `.get()` and Spring will perform the initialization.

```
.from(adapterSpec, e -> ...
```

Comment: I was thinking it and I tried without get(). Obviously I get an error because no poller is associated. I may use a default poller but my original requirement is that also polling time must be configurable for each mail server. Is this feasible in any way?

Comment: ? The poller still goes on the endpoint `from (spec, e -> e.poller(...))` and has nothing to do with the first argument to the `from()`. By passing the spec into the factory method, Spring will initialize the adapter bean.

Comment: Ops you are right... my mistake. I’ll try and let you know

Comment: I confirm my mistake. By removing `.get()` all works pretty good... ah Sherlock Holmes stated.. sometimes you have solutions under your nose but you can't see them :) Thank you